# How to express Jounce from Newton gravity law for Verlet numeric integration scheme?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, physics, kinematics

Despite that terms came from physics, this question is purely about building math model. So I'll try to explain what I want.

1) First of all, I am building a N-body PC simulation program. So I am using numeric [Verlet integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration) scheme, where velocity is replaced by position delta. It could express new position, after small timestep: $x_{new} = x_{old} + (x_{new}-x_{old}) + a\cdot dt^2$. Lets call it (1)

2) As there are multiple bodies, according to [Newton's gravity law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation), for each pair of bodies, attractive force may be calculated $F_1 = m_1 \cdot a_1 = {G m_1 m_2\over r^2}$, where distance between them $r = x_2-x_1$. This can be transormed to finally useful $a_1 = { G m_2\over r^2 }$, lets refer to it as (2)

Plugging (2) into (1) one may get the idea of simulation of objects motion in space.

Now there is third idea, there exists higher order position derivatives, called jerk and [jounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jounce). Trying to extend verlet integration manner to acceleration, I cannot use formula 2 anymore, but have to calculate it another way: $a_{new} = a_{old} + (a_{new}-a_{old}) + jounce\cdot dt^2$. Jerk, like velocity, is of no interest here. Please, correct me if, I am wrong.

Question is, how to "upgrade" newtons gravity law, or how to upgrade formula (2), in order to express jounce, (to be able to calculate acceleration within a process of verlet numeric integration)?

---

Bonus. If you feel this question simple, can you also offer modification of (2) for "pounce"(6-th derivative of position, with respect to time)? Constraints are same: you cannot "touch" acceleration and jounce, but only may calculate them within a process of numeric integration.

Comment: Are you aware that your positions, velocities and accelerations are all vector quantities? So that $a_{12}=\frac{Gm_2}{|r_{12}|^3}r_{12}$? /// Do you really want to get a handle on the higher order derivatives, or do you want a higher error order for the numerical method? There is a direct combination of 3 Verlet steps that gives an overall order 4 step, and there are less expensive combinations of half steps to give a Verlet-like higher order method, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator#A_third-order_example

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann I intentionally omitted it. Consider one dimensional world, please. I want to get handle on higher order and don't care of error much. Also verlet itself is of not much importance. I am interested only in expressing jounce for gravitation law.

Comment: But what is your aim? The gravitation equations are second order, one could use Taylor methods on them which would require higher derivatives, but in general the usual solvers are quite sufficient. Or do you want Verlet like methods for general equations $y^{(4)}=f(y)$ or $y^{(4)}=f(y,y'')$? Then you should look into the derivation for the Numerov methods. But remember, the Verlet method was important for a geometric reason, that it is connected to symplectic methods for Hamiltonion system. I do not see that in the 4th derivative case.

Comment: Also, your Verlet formula should be $$x_{new} = x_{current} + (x_{current}-x_{old}) + a(x_{current})\cdot \Delta t^2.$$ It is a two-step formula resulting from the central second order difference operator.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann  so it is not possible to express gravitation equation for jounce? Like $jounce(x_{current}, a_{current}) = ?$ and my aim is just to see how, or know why its impossible. Don't dig deep, let's omit integrators details and focus only on this formula. How to get it?

Comment: If $r''=-k/r^2$, then $r'''=2kr'/r^3$ and $r^{(4)}=2kr''/r^3-6kr'^2/r^4=-2k^2/r^5-6kr'^2/r^4$. There is no obvious way to get rid of the first derivative. In the "one body in a central field" situation, you can use the conservation of energy to get $r'^2=2k/r+C$, where $C$ is determined by the initial velocity. However, the numerical integration also changes the constants of motion over time, so that replacement will change the properties of the numerical solution. Also, this no longer applies if you change from "one body in a central field" to a N-body simulation.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann Thanks for your input, seems you have derivated something, but I don't understand it fully yet. Basically I want to understand a formula for current jounce applied as input to integrator, (I guess it must include not only pos, but current acceleration as well, to be neat & nice equation space travellers would use) It may and describe our world more exactly) however I lack knowledge to fully understand it. That's interesting question, a mod to newton gravity with respect to current acceleration. Non trivial thing, not invented now))